# Xdocument with Xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, linq-to-xml

using `XDocument` with `xpath` to parse XML
which one is better in perfomance ?

e.g. To search for tag and get value in xml

```
tags = xmlDoc.Descendants(xmlTag);
```

or

```
xml.SelectSingleNode("//root/node")
```

So which one will be faster?

Comment: XDocument and XPath are totally different things... please consider editing your question to make it clear what you want to compare.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XPath doesn't *parse* XML... it's a *query* language used on top of any other XML API which supports it. (For example, you can use XPath over `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`.)

To find out which query would be faster *usefully*, you should try your *actual* XPath and LINQ to XML query on samples of your *actual* data. I would expect XPath to be faster in some situations, and LINQ to XML to be faster in others.

However, I'd be surprised if the query execution speed was actually the bottleneck in your code - do you have evidence that it is? You should first be asking yourself which is *most readable*. Implement that code, then see whether it's *fast enough*.

Comment: Its a just a general question for sake of information about XDocument because i just started working with XDocument and tring to use xpath with xdocument

Comment: @Neo: Well you still *can* use XPath with XDocument - but personally I find it more readable to use the methods provided.